# Set the default browser in Blazor Application

Tags: .net, blazor

The default browser on my system is Chrome, which has my preferred theme and custom settings. In Visual Studio 2022, this same browser is selected as my default browser. When running `asp.net core` projects, this browser launches without any issues. However, when I run `Blazor` project, unfortunately, the program runs in a separate instance of Chrome. This instance lacks my preferred theme and custom settings, and it's not logged into any of my accounts like Gmail.

How can I make sure that my `Blazor` project runs in my default Chrome browser with all my preferred settings? Do I need to make any specific settings in the launchSettings.json file?

My lunchSetting.Json file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5022"
       
    },

    "https": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7272;http://localhost:5022"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1318/",
      "sslPort": 44381
    }
  }
}
```

I have tested the `BrowseWith` settings in Visual Studio 2022 as well as the `preferredBrowser` settings in the launchSettings.json file, and I have also tried a series of other settings, but to no avail.
**Updated**
Unfortunately, I tried `BrowseWith` but there was not any result.

1. [My default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUrrX.jpg)
2. [Find my browser profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEtwr.jpg)
3. [Add browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIhKI.jpg)
4. [Run program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrYFW.png)

Answer (score 1):

For debugging in Visual Studio you can select the webbrowser and you can also add new browsers. Try adding a new instance of your chrome browser to visual studio with arguments and add

```
--profile-directory=Default
```

or

```
--profile-directory="Nameofyourprofile"
```

[image: Visual Studio Browser Selection]
[image: Visual Studio Browser Selection Add]
[image: Visual Studio Browser Selection Details]

[Img Source](https://endjin.com/blog/2020/07/debugging-web-apps-in-visual-studio-with-custom-browser-configurations)

Comment: check my updated post. Instead of -incognito add your own parameters